# Linear Search Algorithm of an Array in reverse order

Tags: java, linear-search

I need to find out an element on an array in reverse manner i.e, checking elements from last element to first

Here is my code

```
public static int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int size = array.length - 1;
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
        if (array[i] == key) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Here my test testcase -

```
count = 10
array  = 44 55 66 77 88 22 11 66 99 33
key = 66
```

its output came 7 which is wrong
its actual output was clearly 2.
I don't know where my logic gone wrong.

Also I don't know how to implement this (if the key is repeated, print the index where the key is appearing for the first time in reverse order.)

Comment: What do you mean with "its output came 7 which is wrong"? Why is it wrong? What output do you expect? If you should return the index of the first match from the back, then 7 should be correct. But as an additional remark, in your for loop, you should run until `i => 0` to also catch the first index in your array.

Comment: actually i need to calculate from last to first of that array like if we want to seach 33 which is last index i.e, 9th index i want to print it as index=0 as im searching from right to left

Comment: Why index=1 then? Shouldn't it be 0 if its the first one from right?

Comment: On my first comment, its obviously `i >= 0`. But can't edit anymore.

Comment: sorry my mistake but you got my question ryt? @maloomeister

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return the number of iterations from the end, you can create an int and return the iteration value

```
   public static int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
        int size = array.length - 1;
        int iteration =-1;
        for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--) {
            iteration++;
            if (array[i] == key) {
                return iteration;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: see test cases

Sample Input:
7
6 8 3 5 9 1 2
9
Sample Output:
2
Here the output is 2 because the position of number 9 is 2 from the reverse order as mentioned in the question.

Comment: in this example with the array [7,6,8,3,5,9,1,2,9] and a key of [9], the answer returned is 0

Answer (score 0):

So after a few inconsitencies regarding what you actually want, I think I got you now. This code should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = { 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 22, 11, 66, 99, 33 };
    int key = 66;
    int result = linearSearch(array, key);
    System.out.println("Index from the right for value " + key + " is: " + result);
}

public static int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int size = array.length - 1;
    for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (array[i] == key) {
            return size - i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The output is:

```
Index from the right for value 66 is: 2
```

Explanation:

The for-loop loops from `size` to `0` backwards. If a match is found, it returns the index from the right, so `size - i`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop

```
for(int i = count-1; i > 0; i--){
            if(key == array[i]){
                int index = ((i+1) - count);
                System.out.print(Math.abs(index));
                break;
            }
        }
```

It will print 2.

Answer (score -1):

If you also want to return a "reversed" index, you must take that into account in your `return` statement:

```
public static int linearSearch(int[] array, int key)
{
    int size = array.length - 1;
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--)
        if (array[i] == key)
            return size - i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please, explain a little how this code solves the problem. Only-code-answers are not welcome at stackoverflow.